# Can someone explain how $\sum_{x=n}^{N} {x \choose n} = {N+1 \choose n+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am going through a proof where it seems that the writer simplified using the equality in the title. This appears to be true but I can't seem to show how and it is not coming intuitively to me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Read up [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have $N+1$ distinct things, arranged in a sequence $\{1,2,\ldots,n,\ldots,N,N+1\}$. How many ways are there to choose a subset of $n+1$? $\binom{N+1}{n+1}$.

On the other hand, you can partition these subsets like:
$$
\begin{align}
&(\text{subsets with maximum }N+1)+(\text{subsets with maximum }N)\\
&+(\text{subsets with maximum }N-1)+\cdots+(\text{subsets with maximum }n+1)
\end{align}$$

Counting how many such subsets there are, you get:

$$\binom{N}{n}+\binom{N-1}{n}+\binom{N-2}{n}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}$$

---

For example, with $\sum_{x=3}^5\binom{x}{n}=\binom{6}{4}$, you have $\binom{6}{4}$ represented as:
$$
\begin{align}
&1236,1246,1256,1346,1356,1456,2346,2356,2456,3456&\text{4-tuples with max 6}\\
&1235,1245,1345,2345&\text{4-tuples with max 5}\\
&1234&\text{4-tuples with max 4}\\
\end{align}
$$

In the top row, there are $\binom{5}{3}$ 4-tuples. Because we have 6 present, and then from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ we must choose the remaining $3$ elements.

In the second row, there are $\binom{4}{3}$ 4-tuples. Because we have 5 present, and then from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ we must choose the remaining $3$ elements.

In the third row, there are $\binom{3}{3}$ 4-tuples. Because we have 4 present, and then from $\{1,2,3\}$ we must choose the remaining $3$ elements.

So $\binom{6}{4}=\binom{5}{3}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{3}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess its the partitioning into subsets that just isn't making sense to me. Is there perhaps a simple way to show algebraically?

Comment: I added a numerical example to help understand how the partitioning works and is counted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, had a lightbulb moment and it makes more sense to me now because of your example!

Answer (score 0):

We have $\binom nk = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$ by Pascal's identity (this is just the fact that in Pascal's triangle, each entry is the sum of the two above it). This can be rearranged to have $\binom nk - \binom{n-1}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k+1}$.

Therefore your sum can be rewritten as
$$
   \sum_{x=n}^N \binom xn = \sum_{x=n}^N \left(\binom{x+1}{n+1} - \binom{x}{n+1}\right)
$$
and now it telescopes to give $\binom{N+1}{n+1} - \binom{n}{n+1} = \binom{N+1}{n+1}$.